# How to create PyQt5 GUI that does not occupy the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

Is it possible to get Python to launch a PyQt5 GUI application using the main thread of execution, and then leave the thread open to do other things?

Here is the simplest example I can think of:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def infinite_useless_loop():
    while True:
        pass

app = QApplication([])
doodad = QMainWindow()
doodad.show()
infinite_useless_loop()
```

If you run this code, it freezes because the 'mainloop' is not activated as it normally would be if I didn't make a call to the useless infinite loop, and instead put a call to `app.exec_()`. The call to `infinite_useless_loop` is meant to substitute the main thread being used to do other useful work **WHILE** the GUI is running correctly.

To do this correctly, I'd have to imagine one would make a separate thread and use that to run the GUI, while launching that thread with the main thread, and just continuing on from there; able to communicate if necessary in the future.

#### EDIT

I wrote some code that gets the main event loop working in a seperate thread, but I am still not able to fully interact with the GUI object that is created in another thread. This code effectively solves half of my problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from threading import Thread
import sys

def makeGUI():
    app = QApplication([])
    doodad = QMainWindow()
    doodad.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def infinite_useless_loop():
    while True:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target=makeGUI)
    thread.start()
    infinite_useless_loop()
```

This code spawns the blank window, able to be clicked on and resized correctly (because the event loop is working), but is on its own. Do I have to revert to signals and slots to communicate with the object, or can I somehow get the GUI object back into the main thread and use it's methods from there?

#### EDIT 2

I do not wish to do any actual GUI manipulation outside of the GUI's thread, just call methods on the GUI object that **I HAVE MADE**. The entire GUI structure would be made by the GUI object.

#### EDIT 3

This new code now makes it able to be communicated with, but only with raw bits of information, and not by one thread accessing another thread's GUI object's methods. This is close, but its still not what I want. Calling the GUI object's methods would have to be done by passing the raw information through the queue, and then being processed at the other side. Then an `exec()` function would have to be called. That is not acceptable. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import multiprocessing
import threading
import sys
import time
import queue

class Application(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, comms):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.comms = comms
        self.fetchingThread = threading.Thread(target=self.fetchingLoop)

        self.labelOne = QLabel(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelOne)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.fetchingThread.start()

    def fetchingLoop(self):
        while True:
            try:
                obj = self.comms.get()
                self.processItem(obj)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def processItem(self, item):
        self.labelOne.setText(str(item))
        print(self.labelOne.text())

class Launcher(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, Application):
        super(Launcher, self).__init__()
        self.comms = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.Application = Application

    def get_comms(self):
        return self.comms

    def run(self):
        app = QApplication([])
        window = self.Application(self.comms)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

def no_thread():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Application(False)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Launcher(Application)
    comms = thread.get_comms()
    thread.start()

    c = 0
    while True:
        c += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        comms.put(c)
```

Comment: Leave PyQt in the main thread and put your other code in a secondary thread.

Comment: I understand that that is a fix, but that was not my question ;)