# Matplotlib plot in a new thread

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-multithreading

I am developing a real-time camera application where a new thread is desired for the plotting. A thread class is created for that:

```
# Create new thread for plotting smoothly
class PlotThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, threadID, fig, ax):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax
        self.h = None
        self.h_raw = None
        self.hr_est = None

    def update_data(self, h, h_raw, hr_est):
        self.h = h
        self.h_raw = h_raw
        self.hr_est = hr_est

    def run(self):
        self.ax[0].clear()
        self.ax[0].plot(self.h)
        self.ax[0].set_title("Filtered signal")
        self.ax[0].text(150, .002, '%s bpm' % int(self.hr_est), fontsize=18)
        self.ax[0].set_ylim((-0.003, 0.003))

        self.ax[1].clear()
        self.ax[1].plot(self.h_raw)
        self.ax[1].set_title("Raw signal")

        plt.pause(0.0000000000001)
```

And the main program looks like that:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(14, 8))
plt_thread = PlotThread(1, fig, ax)

grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult()
while camera.IsGrabbing():
    if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
        # Access the image data
        image = converter.Convert(grabResult)
        frame = image.GetArray()

        h, h_raw, hr_est = core.signal_combination(image)

        plt_thread.update_data(h, h_raw, hr_est)
        plt_thread.start()
```

In that case the time consuming plot do not terminate the program and the camera can start grabbing the next frame -- resulting in a stable framerate.

I get the following error message:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

Comment: I think the GUI event loop needs to be in the main thread always. I implemented something similar once, where the frame grabbing happened in a new thread. The GUI would pull a new frame from the thread whenever it is ready (possibly leading to lost frames when plotting takes too long).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So basically you can run matplotlib only in the main thread?

Comment: To my knowledge and experience, yes. At least the GUI part of matplotlib. But I'm not an expert on these things. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927828/how-to-create-pyqt5-gui-that-does-not-occupy-the-main-thread) (without answer) may be related.